# Algolia add object function not creating objectId

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, algolia

I am trying to create a function that runs on an https request to upload a collection of firestore documents to the algolia servers for index searching.

I have done this successfully with another collection, however this one is not automatically creating the objectId like last time.

I read the algolia documentation and it recommends to use

```
{ autoGenerateObjectIDIfNotExist: true }
```

however that syntax is slightly different than the other cloud function I created to upload a different collection to algolia. I used this article/tutorial to write both functions.
https://medium.com/@soares.rfarias/how-to-set-up-firestore-and-algolia-319fcf2c0d37

.../project/functions/src/index.ts

```
export const uploadGlobalBucketsToAlgolia = functions.runWith({timeoutSeconds: 400}).https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const algoliaRecords: any[] = []
  const querySnapshot = await db.collection('GlobalBuckets').get()

  querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
    const document = doc.data()

    const record = {
      objectId : doc.id,
      bucketCreatorId: document.bucketCreatorId,
      bucketCreatorUsername: document.bucketCreatorUsername,
      bucketId: document.bucketId,
      bucketTitle: document.bucketTitle,
      caption: document.caption,
      commentCount: document.commentCount,
      completed: document.completed,
      completedbucketImageURL: document.completedbucketImageURL,
      createdTimestamp: document.createdTimestamp,
      inspirationCount: document.insirationCount,
      likeCount: document.likeCount,
      mostRecentCollectionId: document.mostRecentCollectionId,
      mostRecentCollectionTitle: document.mostRecentCollectionTitle,
      ownerFCMtoken: document.ownerFCMtoken,
      profileImageURL: document.profileImageURL,
      uid: document.uid,
      username: document.username,
      collectionReferences: document.collectionReferences
    }

    algoliaRecords.push(record)
  })

  collectionGlobalBuckets.saveObjects(algoliaRecords, (_error: any, content: any) => {
    res.status(200).send("Global buckets collection was indexed to Algolia successfully.")
  })
  res.send(algoliaRecords)
})
```

From the documentation it says to upload a documentId, however the array I use to store the document data has a documentId field but am unable to access it.

```
collectionGlobalBuckets.saveObjects(algoliaRecords, { autoGenerateObjectIDIfNotExist: true }).then(({ objectId }) => {
    res.status(200).send("Global buckets collection was indexed to Algolia successfully.")
  })
```

Error:

> 'objectId' is declared but its value is never read.

Here is my firebase log that I used to determine that it may be due to the objectId not being uploaded correctly.

```
2020-10-19T21:27:30.860046917Z D globalBucketsCollectionOnUpdate: Function execution took 188 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
2020-10-19T21:27:33.855935438Z D globalBucketsCollectionOnCreate: Function execution started
2020-10-19T21:27:34.932956286Z D globalBucketsCollectionOnCreate: Function execution took 1079 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
2020-10-19T21:29:18.011004Z I : 
2020-10-19T21:29:18.477917Z I : 
2020-10-19T21:29:19.447697Z N uploadGlobalBucketsToAlgolia: 
2020-10-19T21:30:25.833302Z N uploadGlobalBucketsToAlgolia: 
2020-10-19T21:30:45.414659979Z D uploadGlobalBucketsToAlgolia: Function execution started
2020-10-19T21:30:58.680Z ? uploadGlobalBucketsToAlgolia: Unhandled rejection
2020-10-19T21:30:58.683Z ? uploadGlobalBucketsToAlgolia: { name: 'MissingObjectIDError',
2020-10-19T21:30:58.683Z ? uploadGlobalBucketsToAlgolia:   message:
2020-10-19T21:30:58.683Z ? uploadGlobalBucketsToAlgolia:    'All objects must have an unique objectID (like a primary key) to be valid. Algolia is also able to generate objectIDs automatically but *it\'s not recommended*. To do it, use the `{\'autoGenerateObjectIDIfNotExist\': true}` option.' }
2020-10-19T21:30:58.785616987Z D uploadGlobalBucketsToAlgolia: Function execution took 13371 ms, finished with status: 'connection error'
2020-10-19T21:47:12.846622Z I : 
2020-10-19T21:47:13.195938Z I : 
2020-10-19T21:47:14.127877Z N uploadGlobalBucketsToAlgolia: 
2020-10-19T21:48:32.515157Z N uploadGlobalBucketsToAlgolia: 
2020-10-19T21:48:41.522227723Z D uploadGlobalBucketsToAlgolia: Function execution started
2020-10-19T21:48:56.365Z ? uploadGlobalBucketsToAlgolia: Unhandled rejection
2020-10-19T21:48:56.367Z ? uploadGlobalBucketsToAlgolia: { name: 'MissingObjectIDError',
2020-10-19T21:48:56.367Z ? uploadGlobalBucketsToAlgolia:   message:
2020-10-19T21:48:56.367Z ? uploadGlobalBucketsToAlgolia:    'All objects must have an unique objectID (like a primary key) to be valid. Algolia is also able to generate objectIDs automatically but *it\'s not recommended*. To do it, use the `{\'autoGenerateObjectIDIfNotExist\': true}` option.' }
2020-10-19T21:48:56.471603244Z D uploadGlobalBucketsToAlgolia: Function execution took 14950 ms, finished with status: 'connection error'
2020-10-19T22:00:31.355973248Z D usersCollectionOnUpdate: Function execution started
2020-10-19T22:00:32.943313897Z D usersCollectionOnUpdate: Function execution took 1589 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
2020-10-19T22:06:26.660450Z I : 
2020-10-19T22:06:27.174117Z I : 
2020-10-19T22:06:28.044414Z N uploadGlobalBucketsToAlgolia: 
2020-10-19T22:07:35.324087Z N uploadGlobalBucketsToAlgolia: 
2020-10-19T22:07:56.881712148Z D uploadGlobalBucketsToAlgolia: Function execution started
2020-10-19T22:07:59.266Z ? uploadGlobalBucketsToAlgolia: Unhandled rejection
2020-10-19T22:07:59.269Z ? uploadGlobalBucketsToAlgolia: { name: 'MissingObjectIDError',
2020-10-19T22:07:59.269Z ? uploadGlobalBucketsToAlgolia:   message:
2020-10-19T22:07:59.269Z ? uploadGlobalBucketsToAlgolia:    'All objects must have an unique objectID (like a primary key) to be valid. Algolia is also able to generate objectIDs automatically but *it\'s not recommended*. To do it, use the `{\'autoGenerateObjectIDIfNotExist\': true}` option.' }
2020-10-19T22:07:59.285635593Z D uploadGlobalBucketsToAlgolia: Function execution took 2405 ms, finished with status: 'connection error'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like a TypeScript lint warning about your declaration of `objectId` in this code, which I have formatted for readability:

```
collectionGlobalBuckets.saveObjects(
    algoliaRecords,
    { autoGenerateObjectIDIfNotExist: true }
)
.then(({ objectId }) => {
    res.status(200).send("Global buckets collection was indexed to Algolia successfully.")
})
```

You declare a variable `objectId` destructured from the value passed to `then`, but you never use it anywhere in the function.  Just remove it if you don't need to use it:

```
.then(() => {
    res.status(200).send("Global buckets collection was indexed to Algolia successfully.")
})
```